# Default values of ivars with enum type in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, enums, initialization, default-value, ivar

I have an `enum` like this:

```
typedef enum {
    ThingA,
    ThingB,
    ThingC
} MyType;
```

I have a class with an ivar declared in the interface like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) MyType myTypeIvar;
```

Currently the default value of myTypeIvar is ThingA (since ThingA is in the 0th position in the enum).  **What's the best way to make default value of myTypeIvar ThingB?**

One solution is to simply re-order the enum definition (put ThingB in the 0th position).  Another solution is to set myTypeIvar in the `init` method.  However the init method doesn't exist (and when it's added it's never called).

Comment: So you plan on using this property without properly initializing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the best way to make default value of myTypeIvar ThingB?

Set the value of `myTypeIvar` to `ThingB` in your designated initializer, i.e. the initializer that all other initializers are expected to call. For example, if the class in question is a subclass of UIViewController, you'd override `-initWithNibName:bundle:` because that's the designated initializer for UIViewController.